# Eclipse Commiting to SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I'm trying to commit my changes to my SVN repo, by clicking on the file, team, commit, but then in the Console in eclipse, it says

```
commit -m "" /Users/admin/Documents/workspace/Challenge5-Ghostomatic/GhostList.java
    Skipped
```

And it does that for all the files, even though the local version has changes that the SVN doesnt have. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is `/Users/admin/Documents/workspace/Challenge5-Ghostmatic/` really a working copy of an svn repo? Use `svn status /Users/admin/Documents/workspace/Challenge5-Ghostmatic/` to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "skipped" thing comes from the fact that somewhere, somehow, you corrupted the two trees of files between the repository and your local copy. It is most likely that the issue comes from the fact that you did not merge the two repositories, your local copy, and the subversion copy, before making changes to your file, or adding a file.

Following this tutorial all the way through might help. It's very short and should clear up all your errors.

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/mylyn.php

Answer (score 0):

If you checked out your project using subclipse or the built in subversion client then it should be a local working copy.  You should verify that as kraftan suggested.

If you have somehow corrupted your local copy you can always check out the head revision to a new project area and copy your locally updated files over again. I would suggest backing up your working area before mucking around too much.

What happens if you run a compare with latest from repository?